# two external monitors

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

Can i run two external monitors from a dell 1525? I already use one connected via hdmi, and plan to connect another (if possible) via the same method - using an hdmi / vga adapter, as the 1525 only has a single hdmi socket. I have UltraMon installed. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to your [specs](http://www.dell.com/us/en/dfh/notebooks/inspnnb_1525/pd.aspx?refid=inspnnb_1525&cs=22&s=dfh) your laptop has an Intel 3100 and according to Intel's [specs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=16&ved=0CC0QFjAFOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.intel.com%2Fdesign%2Fembedded%2Fdownloads%2F319611.pdf&rct=j&q=intel+x3100+dual+monitors&ei=nu92S5OzDsqm8AbO8fHzCQ&usg=AFQjCNGsqTUWKpDl65DeKJ4povg4O6LIfA) it supports 2 displays:

> Intel Graphics Media Accelerator X3100
>   supports dual independent displays
>   using an integrated 3D graphics engine
>   with eight graphics cores.

So I would say yes.  Also on the Dell page it lists that your laptop has an HDMI and VGA output, so you should be able to connect one monitor to the HDMI and one to the VGA output.  Since the X3100 supports 2 displays, you laptop's display won't be on when using two monitors.